# Second Monitor not recognized - Trouble with NVIDIA Drivers (RTX 2060)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, xorg

I've recently installed Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish Indri) on my MSI GL75 Leopard. I have an NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 and installed the nvidia-drivers-470. Before installing the proprietary drivers, my second screen was recognized, but now it is not. I've tried a few solutions but so far nothing worked. I am using an HDMI cable for the second monitor.

The NVIDIA X Server application is only showing the Prime Profiles tab, and even when the NVIDIA GPU is selected, Ubuntu is using the integrated Intel graphic card.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot and try again.

Comment: It's already disabled. I think it's just because of Wayland being the default on Ubuntu 21.10. I don't have a problem with the Nouveau drivers so i'll just stick with that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Nouveau will never be able to unleash that card's full potential. You're probably *not* using Wayland (it tends to fallback to X.org if Nvidia with Nvidia drivers is detected) but you can check and try X.org if you confirm you're running Wayland.

Comment: PS - In order to change profiles with Nvidia X Server settings a reboot is still required.

Answer (score 0):

I have been running Impish with Nouveau driver without problems until today. After updating the second monitor over HDMI is no longer detected.

In order to make it work again I installed the proprietary Nvidia driver, restarted (didn't work), then installed Nouveau again, ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm`, restarted again... and monitor is back working.

Needless to say, I have had this issue occasionally over many Ubuntu versions and it hasn't always been easy to work around. Pity it can't be fixed once and for good. :-(

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1227377)